# Breeze - cloning items

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have client application where I want to clone an item and send it to the server and only when the server send notification - to update the entity. is the detachEntity is the only solution? as i want to be able to clone the item and not remove it from the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the specific entity and import it into another entityManager.  This is effectively a clone.

```
var exportedEntities = entityManager1.exportEntities([myEntity]);  
var clonedEntities = entityManager2.importEntities(exportedEntities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code goes here -

```
var thisEntity = getEntity(); 
var newEntity;
var myPropArray = [];
for each property in entity { copy property;  myPropArray.push(property) }
var params = JSON.stringify(myPropArray);
newEntity = manager.createEntity('MyEntityType', params);
```

...

Profit.